# Advanced screen resolution for Corona application development

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I do my first project in Corona. What advanced screen resolution in pxs that I should define in config.lua file? This project will run on different kinds of iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

width 320 and height 480 will be apt for most projects.